# Twilio Python Logging Level

Tags: twilio

How do I set the logging level of twilio python package. My script has a logging config to direct all logs to a file. I would like to limit twilio to log only Warnings.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Twilio Python client uses a logger called `'twilio.http_client'` to log HTTP requests. You should be able to set the log level for the logger with the following:

```
 import logging
 twilio_logger = logging.getLogger('twilio.http_client')
 twilio_logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
```

Let me know if that helps at all.